# Rewrite local history by pulling remote but keep unpushed commits

Tags: git

I recently filtered a lot of bloat files from my remote repository which cleaned a lot of the commits up, but I can't figure out how other developers can pull these changes without rewriting their unpushed commits.

How can other developers pull from my remote and rewrite their history, but maintain their local commits they havent pushed yet? I've tried

```
git fetch origin
git pull --force
```

but this removes their commits, I've also tried

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

but this just gives us merge conflicts. If I simply tell them to `pull`, it will double the commit history.

Comment: *this just gives us merge conflicts* what's wrong with some conflicts? If they worked on the same files as you did, that's bound to happen

Comment: @TimCastelijns we're getting merge conflicts on files from like ... months ago. we've never had a good experience with rebase, either we messed something up early or i don't know, but rebase will give us conflicts starting from literally the first commit. fixing conflicts for the next 700+ commits is not something we want to do

Comment: *If I simply tell them to pull, it will double the commit history.* you could do this and then let them rebase their unpushed commits onto the new history

Comment: @TimCastelijns We just tried that, if we do a `git fetch origin` followed by a `git pull` and `git rebase -i` we just get a ton of `cannot apply <commit>` errors